# Convert scikit-learn SVM model to LibSVM

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, libsvm

I have trained a SVM (svc) using scikit-learn over half a terabyte of data. The model is working fine and I need to port it to C, but I don't want to re-train the SVM from scratch because it takes way too long for me. Is there a way to easily export the model generated by scikit-learn and import it into LibSVM? Internally scikit-learn uses LibSVM so theoretically it should be possible, but I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to easily export the model generated by scikit-learn and import it into LibSVM?

No. The scikit-learn version of LIBSVM has been hacked up severely to fit it into the Python environment and the model is stored as NumPy/SciPy data structures.

Your best shot is to study the [SVM decision function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20134059/166749) and reimplement it in C. The support vectors can be obtained from the `SVC` object as NumPy arrays, which are easily translated to C arrays.

Comment: Reimplementing the decision function doesn't seem particularly problematic, thanks for pointing me to the source code.

Comment: can you please share the decision function implemented in C